# quickbooks and mule integration

Tags: cloud, mule, quickbooks

I am new to quickbooks with Mule, I have to make sample application for Quickbook on premises(i.e desktop app) and cloud based. Where can I find the sample application for Quickbooks and cloud?

I have gone through [link](https://www.mulesoft.com/cloud-connectors/quickbooks-integration-connector), but there is no much information or sample application to connect quickbook with mule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were looking in the wrong site: mulesoft.com is the marketing one, mulesoft.org is the developer's one.

This search https://www.mulesoft.org/connectors?title=quickbooks leads you to the full reference of the two QuickBooks connectors:

- Windows: http://mulesoft.github.io/quickbooks-connector/windows/mule/quickbooks-windows-config.html
- Online Cloud: http://mulesoft.github.io/quickbooks-connector/online/mule/quickbooks-config.html